# Why isn't a element returned in tinkerpop gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin

Why isn't element 7 returned in tinkerpop gremlin query?

I have a graph which connects nodes andwith edges that have a state field.

The states are

- 0 = Unknown
- 1 = Approved
- 2 = Denied

In my query I want to get all connected nodes which are

- connected by only approved edges
- connected by one denied edge to it self or any approved edge
- connected to one of the denied by only approved edges

This are the nodes and edges I have in my samle:

The red edge is denied (2), the dotted are unknown (0).

Below is a script to create this graph in the gremlin console.

[image: Graph]

The following query works fine for node `0`:

```
g.V().
    has('name', eq('0')).
    as('l1').
    repeat(__.
        outE().
        has('State', 1).
        otherV().
        simplePath()
    ).
    emit().
    dedup().
    optional(__.
        as('l2').
        union(
            __.identity(),
            __.select('l1')
        ).
        outE().
        has('State', 2).
        otherV().
        optional(__.
            as('l3').
            repeat(__.
                bothE().
                has('State', 1).
                otherV().
                simplePath()
            ).
            emit().
            dedup().
            union(
                __.identity(),
                __.select('l3')
            )
        ).
        union(
            __.identity(),
            __.select('l2')
        )
    ).
    dedup().
    properties('name')
```

It gives me the nodes `7`, `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `2`.

But when I start at node 1 it only gives me `3`, `0`, `2`, `4`, `5`. I don't understand why `7` is missing. (It's the same query as above but with another name in Line 2)

```
g.V().
    has('name', eq('1')).
    as('l1').
    repeat(__.
        outE().
        has('State', 1).
        otherV().
        simplePath()
    ).
    emit().
    dedup().
    optional(__.
        as('l2').
        union(
            __.identity(),
            __.select('l1')
        ).
        outE().
        has('State', 2).
        otherV().
        optional(__.
            as('l3').
            repeat(__.
                bothE().
                has('State', 1).
                otherV().
                simplePath()
            ).
            emit().
            dedup().
            union(
                __.identity(),
                __.select('l3')
            )
        ).
        union(
            __.identity(),
            __.select('l2')
        )
    ).
    dedup().
    properties('name')
```

Here the script to create the graph in gremlin console

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = traversal().withEmbedded(graph)

g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '0')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '1')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '2')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '3')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '4')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '5')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '6')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '7')
g.addV('InquiryEntity').property(single, 'name', '8')


g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '0').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '1').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '2').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '3').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '4').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '5').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '6').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '7').as('l1').V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', '8').addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).to('l1').outV().addE('CompareEntity').property('State', 0).from('l1')

g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('0').or(eq('1'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('1').or(eq('0')))).property('State', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('1').or(eq('2'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('2').or(eq('1')))).property('State', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('1').or(eq('3'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('3').or(eq('1')))).property('State', 2)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('0').or(eq('4'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('0').or(eq('4')))).property('State', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('4').or(eq('5'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('4').or(eq('5')))).property('State', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('0').or(eq('5'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('0').or(eq('5')))).property('State', 1)
g.V().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('3').or(eq('7'))).outE('CompareEntity').where(__.otherV().hasLabel('InquiryEntity').has('name', eq('3').or(eq('7')))).property('State', 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `emit` to before the `repeat` otherwise node "1" will not be part of the starting set and the only way to get to "7" goes through "1". This of course does mean that the starting vertex is included in the results. To remove the starting vertex from the results you can add `where(neq('l1'))` after the `dedup` at the end of the query.

```
gremlin>     g.V().
......1>     has('name', '1').
......2>     as('l1').
......3>     emit().
......4>     repeat(__.
......5>         outE().
......6>         has('State', 1).
......7>         otherV().
......8>         simplePath()
......9>     ).
.....10>     dedup().
.....11>     optional(__.
.....12>         as('l2').
.....13>         union(
.....14>             __.identity(),
.....15>             __.select('l1')
.....16>         ).
.....17>         outE().
.....18>         has('State', 2).
.....19>         otherV().
.....20>         optional(__.
.....21>             as('l3').
.....22>             repeat(__.
.....23>                 bothE().
.....24>                 has('State', 1).
.....25>                 otherV().
.....26>                 simplePath()
.....27>             ).
.....28>             emit().
.....29>             dedup().
.....30>             union(
.....31>                 __.identity(),
.....32>                 __.select('l3')
.....33>             )
.....34>         ).
.....35>         union(
.....36>             __.identity(),
.....37>             __.select('l2')
.....38>         )
.....39>     ).
.....40>     dedup().
.....41>     properties('name')
==>vp[name->7]
==>vp[name->1]
==>vp[name->3]
==>vp[name->0]
==>vp[name->2]
==>vp[name->5]
==>vp[name->4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding from after the simplepath()
you can add .from('l3') on both statement which will make the path starts from there. otherwise the simplepath will always start from the begining.

```
g.V().
has('name', eq('1')).
as('l1').
repeat(__.
    outE().
    has('State', 1).
    otherV().
    simplePath()
).
emit().
dedup().
optional(__.
    as('l2').
    union(
        __.identity(),
        __.select('l1')
    ).
    outE().
    has('State', 2).
    otherV().
    optional(__.
        as('l3').
        repeat(__.
            bothE().
            has('State', 1).
            otherV().
            simplePath().from('l3')
        ).
        emit().
        dedup().
        union(
            __.identity(),
            __.select('l3')
        )
    ).
    union(
        __.identity(),
        __.select('l2')
    )
).
dedup().
properties('name')
 ==>vp[name->7]
 ==>vp[name->0]
 ==>vp[name->3]
 ==>vp[name->2]
 ==>vp[name->4]
 ==>vp[name->5]
```